# how to resolve the issue changing name of application delegate in InterfaceBuilder

Tags: ios, xcode, iboutlet

following is the screen shot which is having issue in interface builder

[image: screenshot1]

i have tried all possible connections yet couldn’t resolve this issue

[image: screenshot2]

i know to resolve this i must connect navigation controller and window to IBOutlet properties of AppDelegate but don't know which all to connect exactly ..

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

as i guess Stage1ReceipeAppDelegate must have a delegate of UIApplicationDelegate